# unknown size list to string display in powerBI dax

Tags: string, list, powerbi, dax

So I'm currently working on some powerBI stuff, and I have a database table which is hierarchic, meaning I have something like this:

__id___Place______id_parent

1. London_____null
2. Paris________null
3. Madrid_____null
4. MyInc_________1
5. Building1_____4
6. Building2_____4
7. Floor1________5
8. Floor2________5

using the PATH() dax function, I can get a list like so (7, 5, 4, 1), and I'd like to get from that unknown size list a string to display like so "Floor1 -> Building1 -> MyInc -> London"

Any idea how I can achieve that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK i give you a hint. My columns -> ID, Place, ParentId.

(of course you can do this in one step)

Generate a Path:

```
Path = PAtH(ParentChild[id], ParentChild[parent_id])
```

Check Item on specyfic position:

```
topLevel1 = PATHITEM(ParentChild[Path],1)
topLevel2 = PATHITEM(ParentChild[Path],2)
```

Make somethingelse:

```
Top1_2 = 
var l1 = LOOKUPVALUE(ParentChild[Place],ParentChild[id],VALUE(ParentChild[topLevel1]))
var l2a = LOOKUPVALUE(ParentChild[Place],ParentChild[id],VALUE(ParentChild[topLevel2]))
var l2 = if(ISBLANK(l2a), "", " -> " & l2a)
return
CONCATENATE(l1,l2)
```

[image]

DisplayPath =
var __Path =PAtH(ParentChild[id], ParentChild[parent_id])
var __P1 = PATHITEM(__Path,1)
var __P2 = PATHITEM(__Path,2)
var l1 = LOOKUPVALUE(ParentChild[Place],ParentChild[id],VALUE(__P1))
var l2a = LOOKUPVALUE(ParentChild[Place],ParentChild[id],VALUE(__P2))
var l2 = if(ISBLANK(l2a), "", " -> " & l2a)
return
CONCATENATE(l1,l2)

Comment: can't get it  to work, you are using the 'Path' column in "topLevel1 = PATHITEM(ParentChild[Path],1)" which I can't because I'm in direct connect and can't modify the tables

Comment: check my update. Check if this work for you as CalculatedColumn

Comment: It returns an error: calcul error in 'ParentChild'[DisplayPath]: A multi value table was given but a unique value was intended. I guess it comes from var __p1 = ...

Comment: In CalculateColumn or Measure?

Comment: Do you create a new Measure or a new CalculatedColumn? Error is in both? i check this on ma sample (not directquery) and as CalculatedColumn its work ok

Comment: When creating a new column dax don't let me use PATH, or any other function. My final goal is to use it on a drillthrought page so it can only be applied on one id at a time

Comment: after some research, I can't use PATH in a DirectQuery new column

Comment: Maybe you can make a copy of this table (only this one) and switch mode to import? Or even a subset of table. This kind of data changes rather slow. ps. sorry, i don't remember all limitations of direct query because we don't use them.

Comment: can you auto-refresh my data with a non-DirectQuery connection? if so I can turn to a normal connection and then problem solved... Or just create an other table that take the data from my hierarchical one

Comment: we use Scheduled refresh once a day on app.powerbi (on-prem data gateway).

Comment: Oh, I see, so I can. Then I'm gonna change that :) It should work fine as you tried it. Thanks a lot!